# How to loop through two files line-by-line?

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to run this two files line, connecting each word from each file, but its reading the whole files.

my sample data file 1:

```
work
play
```

my sample data file 2:

```
ed
ing
```

I want this result  connecting two word together:

```
worked
playing
```

but I'm getting:

```
working 
worked 
playing
played
```

I just want to read it line by line from each file:

my code:

```
file1 = []


file2 = []


with open('file1.txt','rU') as f:
    for line in f:
        #print line.rstrip()
       file1.append(line.rstrip())


with open('file2.txt','rU') as f1: #cnn-lm input
    for line1 in f1:
       #print line1.rstrip()
       file2.append(line1.rstrip())


resutl=[]
f=open('output.txt', "w")

for i in file1 :
    for g  in file2 :

            temp=[]
            temp.append(i)
            temp.append(g)


                w = (i + g) 

            temp.append(w)
            result=i+','+g+','+str(w)

            f.write(result)
            f.write('\n')
            print w
f.close()
```

Answer (score 5):

That's expected because you're doing a double loop, aka a *product* of your terms.

You have to interleave them instead, with a simple loop and `zip`, like this:

```
with open('file1.txt','rU') as f1, open('file2.txt','rU') as f2:
    for s,e in zip(f1,f2):
        print("{}{}".format(s.rstrip(),e.rstrip()))
```

I get

```
working
played
```

Comment: Thanks you for your quick replay. with my code above it doesn't run because, the line should  (one by one) for example loop1 A + B loop2 C+D

Comment: My suggestion replaces your code completely apart for the 'write to file' bit

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is to zip the files together, and include the output file in the same `with` block.

```
with open('file1.txt','rU') as f1, open('file2.txt', 'rU') as f2, open('output.txt', "w") as fo:
    for line1, line2 in zip(f1, f2):
        fo.write("{}{}\n".format(line1.rstrip(), line2.rstrip()))
```

Comment: `writeln`: that's Pascal.

Comment: Well, Pascal is way under-used. It needs some promoting. ;-) I have changed it now.